# Selector for cheerio (Node.js) working in console but not in my script

Tags: javascript, node.js, cheerio

I'm writing a simple script to scrape a currency table from a website.

This is my script so far and what I want to do is to get the table of FOREX rates from this website: https://www.bangkokbank.com/en/Personal/Other-Services/View-Rates/Foreign-Exchange-Rates

This is my code so far.

```
const cheerio = require('cheerio');
const request = require('request');

request({
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'https://www.bangkokbank.com/en/Personal/Other-Services/View-Rates/Foreign-Exchange-Rates'
}, (err, res, body) => {

    if (err) return console.error(err);
    let $ = cheerio.load(body);
    var x = [];
    var hello = $("#exchange-rates > div.table-outer > table > tbody> tr > td");
    
    console.log(hello);


    $("#exchange-rates > div.table-outer > table > tbody> tr > td").each((i, elem) => {
        x.push($(elem).text());
        console.log($(elem).text());
    });
    
});
```

When I run "$("#exchange-rates > div.table-outer > table > tbody> tr > td")" in the console on the webpage (by clicking inspect), it is able to identify all the relevant elements. But it's not getting anything when I run the script in JavaScript.

Could anyone advise? thank you!

Comment: you requiring a package `request`, is that the `deprecated` [request - npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request)?

Comment: Ah yes! But it should still work i guess

Comment: Does this line work as expected even if you do not explicitly `listen` to the response object `error` event...? `if (err) return console.error(err);`; and how are you supposed to `consume` your response if you do not explicitly `listen` for the `end` event and consume that result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The given path does not exist in the static website. This website renders content dynamically, i.e, once the web content is delivered on the browser, further DOM manipulation takes place to render data. So, the static web page has only `"#exchange-rates > div.table-outer > table > tbody`. The `tr`, `td` tags are appended once it is fetched on the browser. You may have to look at any other alternate solutions to get the forex exchange rates, say using any existing APIs.